# Is there a way to set the locale used by NuGet to Neutral (English)?

Tags: nuget

I have set up localized (Russian) Windows 7. It is Professional rather than Ultimate or Enterprise, so I cannot set up English language pack or MUI. Then, I have set up Visual Studio (English) with Nuget extension. The fact of the matter is that for some reason Nuget sends its messages to output log in the language of system localization instead of language of Visual Studio/msbuild, while messages from .Net SDK go in English. What I'd like to have is output in English, for example, to send it to English speaker.

It looks like there is no way to confiugure it in Nuget.config file. At least, this option is not mentioned explicitly in [documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings). Also, I did not find any language settings in Nuget extension itself.

Is there a working way or workaround to get Nuget output in English in spite of the system locale?

Comment: Since NuGet version 3.5, you can use the `-ForceEnglishOutput` switch with every command to force NuGet to output everything in English. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a global configuration for that.